# Change the color of two "div" by clicking on some, program through Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem, I want to change the color of two "div" by clicking on some, program through Javascript.

```js
function intercambiar() {
  getElementById('micolor').background.color = 'Red'; //error
  getElementById('Rojo').background.color = '#465620';
}

function mensaje() {
  alert("Name");
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 40%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

#Rojo {
  background-color: red;
}

#micolor {
  background-color: #465620;
}
```

```html
<div id="Rojo" onclick="intercambiar()"></div>
<div id="micolor" onclick="mensaje()"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.style.backgroundColor` on the `div` elements.

Oh, and it's `document.getElementById` not `[window.]getElementById`!

Here's the working code:

```js
function intercambiar() {
 document.getElementById('micolor').style.backgroundColor = 'Red'; //error
 document.getElementById('Rojo').style.backgroundColor ='#465620';
}
function mensaje() {
 alert("Name");
}
```

```css
div{
 width: 40%;
 height: 300px;
 border: 1px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: black;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 10px;

 }
 #Rojo{
 background-color: red;
 }

 #micolor{
 background-color: #465620; 
}
```

```html
<div id="Rojo"    onclick="intercambiar()"></div>
<div id="micolor" onclick="mensaje()"></div>
```

Comment: @LeeTaylor Yeah, just noticed that when writing the snippet! All working now.

Comment: Thank you, your response was very helpful, error solved.